# Rest mass of the nucleus and its constituent nucleons

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, mass, nuclear-physics

One of the question in my book says that if $E$ denote the rest mass energy of a nucleus and $n$ a neutron then,

a.) $E(U^{236}_{92})>E(I^{137}_{53})+E(Y^{97}_{39})+2E(n)$

b.)$E(U^{236}_{92})<E(I^{137}_{53})+E(Y^{97}_{39})+2E(n)$

c.) $E(U^{236}_{92})<E(Ba^{137}_{53})+E(Kr^{97}_{39})+2E(n)$

d.) $E(U^{236}_{92})=E(Ba^{137}_{53})+E(Kr^{97}_{39})+2E(n)$

As far as I have studied I can easily quote from my book that **the rest mass energy of a nucleus is smaller than the rest mass energy of its constituent nucleons in free state**. There difference is the binding energy. So by no way is the first option correct but my book says that the right option is the first one. How can be this be? Am I missing some points/concepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the rest mass energy of a nucleus is smaller than the rest mass energy of its constituent nucleons in free state

This sentence speaks about $protons$ and $neutrons$ as the constituents. In your equation you have three nuclei and the sentence is valid for each of the three nuclei separately.

Your quiz question wants you, however, to compare in more detail the masses of the nuclei on the right with that on the left. And from the conservation of energy, you may have constituents flying away with some kinetic energy on expense of the binding energy of the left side.

Answer (score 0):

The BE per nucleon is higher in the region of mass number where you have the two fission fragments as compared to the region of mass number 236. Therefore you get the answer. Higher BE lower rest mass.